# Can I open Osmand with a link pointing to a GPS Position?

Tags: osmand

I want to generate a link with a gps position so that, when clicked, Osmand opens and shows the location, similar to http://maps.google.com/?q=latitude,longitude, but it should open in the app so that the offline maps are used.

Is this possible?